# jquery modal dialog loading another page, how to submit the form within the dialog and without refresh parent page

Tags: jquery

I have a page (page A) contains a jquery modal dialog, which contains another page (page B), on that page, I will do a form submit, however, once the form is submit, the whole page get refreshed (page A is gone, only the page B displayed).

can I just submit the form in dialog and keep the dialog open?

I want a solution other than iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this Ajax form jquery plugin:

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/